# Поразрядная сортировка

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, структуры-данных

Почему поразрядная сортировка использует в качестве ключа сортировки индексы именно справа налево, а не наоборот?

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень "узкий". На него при такой постановке практически никто не сможет ответить, т.к. отвечающий человек должен досконально знать "правила сортировки", или сам реализовывать механизм СУБД. Опубликуюте хотя бы ссылки на источники где это описано.

Comment: http://padaread.com/?book=120240&pg=77    77 и 78 страницы

Answer (score 5):

Потому что наоборот, сортируя по наименее значащему разряду, вы просто испортите отсортированность по старшему, только и всего.

справа налево:

```
123  450  221  123  
221  221  123  221
453  123  450  450
450  453  453  453
```

слева направо:

```
123  123  123  450  
221  221  221  221
453  453  453  123
450  450  450  453
```

Видите - на последней сортировке по младшему разряду у вас 450 становится меньше 221, а оно меньше 123... :(

Answer (score 2):

Поразрядная сортировка подразумевает сначала стабильную сортировку по самой малозначащей части ключа, затем - стабильную сортировку по следующей по значимости части ключа, затем - стабильную сортировку по еще более высокой по значимости части ключа и т.д. до самой значащей части ключа. Сортировка по наиболее значимой части ключа должна делаться в последнюю очередь.

Поразрядная сортировка "справа-налево" обычно описывается в контексте сортировки чисел *по значению*, т.е. в контексте, где ключ `10` *больше*, чем ключ `2` (в отличие от *лексикографической* сортировки, где ключ `10` *меньше*, чем ключ `2`). Так как мы привыкли записывать числа "справа-налево", т.е. значимость разряда в привычной нам записи числа возрастает справа-налево, то и поразрядная сортировка набора чисел, представленных в привычной нам записи, выглядит для нас как обрабатывающая разряды справа-налево.